# How to assert verify the access of case class fields in scala?

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I wanted to know and assert whether case class has been accessed or not ?
For instance in java value objects i can assert on getters to verify whether the instance variables of value objects were accessed or not . In scala i want to achieve similar thing while accessing case class fields.

```
case class Student(id:Int,name:String,department:String)

public def insertDataIntoTable(sc: Student = Student(1,"pspk","ap")) : Unit ={

  val id =  transform(sc.id)
  val name = transform(sc.name)
val dept = transform(sc.department)

}
```

In the above code snippet i would like to add unit-test to verify id , name , department fields were accessed 1 time every time insertDataIntoTable is executed.

With the help of mockito how can i achieve that in unit-tests ?

Any inputs are much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Mockito is better suitable for imperative programming, as it helps you confirm that effectful functions have actually been used. If your code is pure and functional, there is no need for that - you can do black-box testing.

Comment: Thank you , but there are cases where we want to write data to the database and we want that code to remain with us till the end of application cycle. We don't want anyone to change that code. For the same reason unit-tests would be a safety net in case if someone breaks the functionality.  How to unit-test such cases ? In order to do black box testing i need to write integration test / database access which is not possible as i don't have test environment with me everytime i check in the code to ci/cd pipeline

Comment: This is the incorrect mindset for FP. Instead of asserting that a certain value has been used in your side-effect-ful `transform(...)`, you should create a function called `prepareInsertDataIntoTableStatement` that creates a set of instructions (maybe a SQL query, maybe an `IO`, maybe some other DSL). This set of instructions can be tested to never change. For the productive code, only in the very last step you actually execute this set of instructions on the database, either by sending the query, or by executing the `IO`. This very last part will not be covered by unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Mockito.spy](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.26.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) in combination with [Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.26.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#never_verification) like so:

```
class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  case class Student(id: Int, name: String, department: String)

  "Student case class" should "not have interactions" in {
    val student = Mockito.spy(Student(1, "Mario", "Starfleet Academy"))
    student.department // access case class field
    Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(student)
  }
}
```

This should fail with:

```
No interactions wanted here:
-> at example.HelloSpec.$anonfun$new$1(HelloSpec.scala:12)
But found this interaction on mock 'student':
-> at example.HelloSpec.$anonfun$new$1(HelloSpec.scala:11)
```

`spy` enables inspecting interactions with *real* objects such as case classes, whilst `verifyZeroInteractions` does what it says on the tin.